# How do you detect if a Ruby instance has been changed after creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you detect if a Ruby instance has been changed after creation?

I'm trying to stay away from known gems like ActiveModel::Dirty and writing a lightweight solution that will return a simple true or false if the Object's instance variables have been changed after some point.

This is also for a regular Ruby Object, not a Rails Object so Rails specific tools don't work.

I saw some posts on hijacking attr_writer, but I didn't know if this was comprehensive and I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, you can get some ideas from reading source code of abovementioned `ActiveModel::Dirty`.

Comment: Also, a solution is either lightweight or comprehensive. If it was possible to do both, ActiveModel::Dirty would have been done that way.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no lightweight solution for this. A possible hack could be to write a C extension which plugs into the GC and checks if some instance variable was changed.

Comment: GC? It doesn't track changes, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't track changes as it is, I think.